# Drupal 7 feeds, permission-error with oauth for instagram ("public_content")

Tags: drupal, instagram-api, drupal-feeds

earlier in 2015 i started creating a website with drupal 7 that imports instagram-content (images, likes, comments etc.) via Drupal Feeds. Everything worked finde, but the projects stopped then.

Now it seems we start that again but suddenly the import is not working anymore. I always get the following error:

> {"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "code": 400,
>   "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this
>   access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must
>   re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted
>   this permissions."}}

I didnt had to send the "public_content" earlier, so i was just sending "basic"-scope access. And as i said, everything worked well. 
Now i inserted also the scope for "public_content" along with "basic" within the oauth-Module for feeds. But still getting the error-message above.

Any hints on that?

Thanks in advance and regards,
Fab

Comment: I am interested to know how did you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

[This is due to a Instagram Platfrom Update](http://developers.instagram.com/post/145262544121/instagram-platform-update-effective-june-1-2016)

You'll have to add public_content scope as Joshi has pointed out - and also you'll need to renew your auth token in the settings page.

Then you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
Use following code in instagram_social_feed.module 
Function: instagram_social_feed_settings()

```
 if (variable_get('instagram_social_feed_client_id', '') != '' && variable_get('instagram_social_feed_redirect_uri', '') != '') { 
      $form['authenticate'] = array( 
        '#markup' => l(t('Click here to authenticate via Instagram and create an access token'), 
         'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=' . variable_get('instagram_social_feed_client_id') . '&redirect_uri=' . variable_get('instagram_social_feed_redirect_uri') . '&response_type=code&scope=public_content' 
        ) 
      ); 
    }
```

This will solve the issus